Unable to set up CalDav server for syncing calenders
I have been trying to sync the Thunderbird calender that I use on Ubuntu 20.04 laptop with an Android calender app on my phone (probably OneCalender), without using Google.
Discovered CalDav and trying to set up a Radicale CalDav server(https://radicale.org/v3.html) but very complicated for a not-so-tech savvy person like myself.
I followed the steps of this tutorial closely:
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-radicale-caldav-and-carddav-on-ubuntu-20-04/
No success unfortunately. When running the {start radicale} command I get this result:
scrngrb ubuntu terminal
Anyone here with suggestions on possible solutions or references to better resources and instructions?
Thanks a lot!

Please do not post pictures of text, cut and paste the text into the body of the question. There are several reasons for this. Having a pictures requires loading a different screen to see it. You can not search or work with the text such as formatting it for easier reading.

can you post output from journalctl --unit radicale.service

journalctl --unit radicale.service give me: [CRITICAL] Invalid file configuration: Invalid option: 'filesystem locking' in section 'st>
Think I know what this refers to as it it's one of the steps in the how to forge tutorial that I posted. Should I remove the filestyem locking line in the Storage section of the radicale/config file or is it not placed right?
Currently looks like this:
#Folder for storing local collections, created if not present
filesystem_folder = /var/lib/radicale/collections
filesystem_locking = True

I have tried without the filesystem_locking line in the config file but still fails and renders same output for journalctl
